# How to pass javascript variable values inside expression engine as embed tag?

Tags: javascript, expressionengine

```
 var stext=someresult;

 {embed="reports/contact_form"  email_me= "{stext}"}
```

How can I pass the javascript variable or function value inside above expression engine 
  embed tag .

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

The reason is the same as why you can't do it with PHP either.
If you need functionality with data between serverside (PHP) and clientside (JavaScript) you have to do this with AJAX.

Comment: Repox is correct. Use JS to manage the `stext` variable instead of trying to pass it through EE.